# Accessing dependencies with in a js function

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to use dropzone.js with in Sweetalert2.
When I am just letting it load everting is working but if I am using it with in a function it is not anymore. (example below)

```
<link href="./dropzone-5.7.0/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="./sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- 2 -->
<script src="./dropzone-5.7.0/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<div > <a id="new_pic" >Add</a></div>
<script>
// working  
Swal.fire('<form action="page"  style="max-width: 100%; "    class="dropzone"    id="my-awesome-dropzone"><input  style="max-width: 100%; "  type="file" name="file" /></form>  ')


// not working
document.getElementById("new_pic").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    
    Swal.fire({
  
  title: 'Upload',
  html:'<form action="page"  style="max-width: 100%; "    class="dropzone"    id="my-awesome-dropzone"><input  style="max-width: 100%; "  type="file" name="file" /></form>'
  
})
}
</script>
```

[first example(working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYaKc.png)
[second not working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVFqT.png)

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: The problem is that dropzone is just working in the first example and not inside myFunction().